# SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT does nothing

Tags: python, django, http, security, https

I have set `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT` in my settings to `True`.

> If True, the SecurityMiddleware redirects all non-HTTPS requests to HTTPS (except for those URLs matching a regular expression listed in SECURE_REDIRECT_EXEMPT).

I've also set `PREPEND_WWW = True` and `BASE_URL = "https://www.******.com"`

My site is usually HTTPS:

[image]

But I've purposely embedded a HTTP image in a page which has turned it to this:

[image]

However when I go on that page, it doesn't redirect to HTTPS. Why is this and how can I fix it?

PS: Here is my middleware if that matters:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: This middleware/setting only applies to requests served by Django. Django doesn't normally handle requests for media/images - so it will have no effect on those. You need to configure your web server not to serve media over HTTP.